# y axis values are merged together in ggplot r

Tags: r, ggplot2

So I'm plotting a plot of S&P prices vs time for 2020/2021. When I try to plot my code the values on the y axis cannot be read as they all merge together . The price values are between 2000 and 4000 so I don't know why they are being removed.
[image]

When I try adding in scale_y_discrete a warning message occurs:

```
plot7 <-  ggplot(data= SNP500_2020_2021_Historical_Data, mapping = aes(x=Date,y=Price,group=1)) + 
  geom_line(size=0.25)+ 
  labs(title= "SNP 2020-2021", x= "Date", y= "Price")+ 
  theme_minimal()

plot7 + 
  scale_x_date(date_breaks= "1 month", date_labels = "%Y-%m") + 
  scale_y_discrete(limits=c("2000.00","3000.00","4000.00"))+ 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(face= "bold",  hjust = 1 , angle = 90)) + 
  theme(axis.text.y = element_text(face="bold"))+  theme(axis.line = element_line(color="grey", size = 0.25))
```

> ```
> Warning messages:
> 1: Removed 299 row(s) containing missing values (geom_path). 
> 2: Position guide is perpendicular to the intended axis. Did you mean to specify a different guide `position`?
> ```

Comment: This looks like something is going very wrong. Your y-axis should not be a discrete axis. Possibly, `Price` has been read in wrong and is a `character` vector or a `factor`. Check `str(SNP500_2020_2021_Historical_Data)` and make sure your variables are of the correct types. Once fixed, use `scale_y_continuous` instead of `scale_y_discrete`.

Comment: Yes @Axeman it seems as though the Price variable is in character form. Do you know how I would change this , what form is it meant to be in ?

Comment: Try `ggplot(data= SNP500_2020_2021_Historical_Data, mapping = aes(x=Date,y=as.numeric(Price),group=1))` and then `scale_y_continuous(limits=c(2000,4000), breaks = seq(2000,4000,1000))`

Comment: @EllenHynes since it is a price I assume you want it to be numeric. You can change it with `as.numeric`, but it is worth checking out why it is being read in as a character vector in the first place.